# jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: event.preventDefault is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that countdown time when start button is clicked  when time reach 0 form should do auto-submit but the the form submit twice when I use preventDefault() output error event.preventDefault is not a function

Here is my code

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#startbutton').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            var t = $(this).attr('timevalue');
            var fiveMinutes = 60 * parseInt(t);
            $(function ($) {
                $('#festus').hide();
                display = $('#time');
                startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
            });
        });                

        function startTimer(duration, display) {
            var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
            var __timer = setInterval(function () {
            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

            display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

             if (--timer < 0) {
                 clearInterval(__timer);
                 var form_id = $('#questionsandanswers').serializeArray();
                        var url = $('#questionsandanswers').attr('action');


               $(function (event) {
                   event.preventDefault();
                    $.post(url, form_id, function (data) {
                        alert('time is up you can no longer proceed');
                    });
                });
            }                      
         },1000);
    }
});
</script>
```

what can I do to avoid form to submit twice

Comment: Why you have a strange DOM ready `$(function ($) {` inside a DOM ready `$(document).ready(function (e) {` ? And what's that `e` ? You *can* use DOM ready but not nesting them. Preferably like: `jQuery(function( $ ) {`

Comment: No that e on $(document).ready(function (e) does not exist

Comment: Yes, it existed [12 minutes ago before vanishing after your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50620248/revisions)

Answer (score 1):

since your html is missing, but you wrote you want to submit one, you should do something like this:

```
$(function() {
 $('#form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.prevenDefault(); // stops submitting the form

        //timer logic here
        // ...
        // then call $.post to submit your form via ajax
  });
});
```

Don't nest your jQuery Dom-Ready functions.

Comment: On line number 3, It should be         event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is right here:

```
$(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
     $.post(url, form_id, function (data) {
          alert('time is up you can no longer proceed');
     });
}
```

`$(function)` is a jQuery way of saying you want to execute a function immediately after the page loads (similar to `$(document).ready`). The `event` parameter is not defined in that scope.

Perhaps you might want to put that piece of code somewhere else? You could try defining a separate function, where you call `$.post` and call it when the timer runs out.

```
function postForm(url, form_id){
    $.post(url, form_id, function (data) {
        alert('time is up you can no longer proceed');
    });
}

function startTimer(duration, display) {
        var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;

        var __timer = setInterval(function () {
            //...........

            if (--timer < 0) {
                clearInterval(__timer);

                var form_id = $('#questionsandanswers').serializeArray();
                var url = $('#questionsandanswers').attr('action');

                postForm(url, form_id);
            }
        },1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: So what is your suggestion @Baksteen because event here is auto-submit, how can I use preventDefault(); to prevent double submit?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I don't think I can help you any further without more clarification on your part.

Comment: The function itself is working fine but the problem is that the when form is submitted is submitted twice and I want to prevent that, that's the problem here Buddy.

Comment: I was missing e.stopImmediatePropagation() when start button is clicked because startTimer(duration, display) has been called when button is clicked, Thanks for help it was overwhelming for 2 days.